# how to open an spesific form(ui) when get firebase data message in xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am try to to open a xamarin form  when i get a spesific message from firebse . i can  make a simple notification with a  a spesific title and then my app should  react for that notification . i tried to do it and it doesn't work .I am trying it on android platform and the form which i want open is locatated at cross platform package

my code

```
namespace DT.Samples.Agora.Cross.Droid
{
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    public class MyMessagingService:FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        private readonly string NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID="noty";

        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage p0)
        {
            base.OnMessageReceived(p0);

            
         

            if (p0.GetNotification().Title.Equals("hey"))
            {

               

                Log.Debug("succes", "noty: " + p0.Ttl);
            }

            if (!p0.Data.GetEnumerator().MoveNext())
            {
                SendNotidication(p0.GetNotification().Title, p0.GetNotification().Body);
            }
            else 
            {
           SendNotidication(p0.Data);
            }
        }

        private void SendNotidication(IDictionary<string, string> data)
        {
            string title, body;

            data.TryGetValue("title", out title);
            data.TryGetValue("body", out body);

            SendNotidication(title, body);
        }

        private void SendNotidication(string title, string body)
        {
          NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Notification Channel",
                    Android.App.NotificationImportance.Default
                    );

                notificationChannel.Description = "EDMTDev Channel";
                notificationChannel.EnableLights(true);
                notificationChannel.LightColor = Color.Blue;
                notificationChannel.SetVibrationPattern(new long[] { 0, 1000, 500, 1000 });

                notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);


            }

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificaionBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

            notificaionBuilder.SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetDefaults(-1)
            .SetWhen(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds())
            .SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetContentText(body)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.belicon)
            .SetContentInfo("info");

            notificationManager.Notify(new Random().Next(), notificaionBuilder.Build());
            //dGNlRe7p73w:APA91bFqU7GxoVfw1ljNTGrvgpMMEs-Y7nh9W3k1Uecns2I88BUTQrSdrr3nyl0eNFHeKbWRn6ZFS0e_VNcBWSW0L-wYKv81tPddLyTaH_6IHPE6oWlKcdaMn_zsiLiaH8aJXch-xnRj

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code where you are attempting to navigate to a certain page?

Comment: i am new for xamarin and i don't know how to dot it, and i am tried using this code  " Navigation.PushAsync(new carDetails(details));" but  it does not work for me

Comment: use `MessagingCenter`

Comment: i am sorry . i am new for xamarin and if you don't mind can you provide sample code?

Comment: please take the time to read the relevant docs, and if you have additional questions then ask them.  I don't have time at the moment to provide you with a complete tutorial

Comment: i tried it . it does't work (" MessagingCenter.Send(this, "login"); ")

Comment: For notification, it seems work. You could check the sample in the link below for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60702921/how-to-open-contentpage-on-xamrin-forms-while-receiving-fcm-notification/60717570#60717570 Have you call this Service? When you debug one by one, could you call the `SendNotidication`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a Xamarin.Forms app, you can call `MyCrossPlatformProject.App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MyPage());`

This will call the App's running instance and it will be able to "open" the page you want by pushing it to the navigation stack. This will only work if `App` has been initialized. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: when use it i get an error ath "the name cross platform project does not exist in the current context"